# Отличие веб - сервера, сервера приложений и микросервиса

Tags: веб-сервер

Только начинаю изучать веб. Назрело много вопросы, очень буду благодарен за помощь.

1. В чем отличие между веб сервером и сервером приложений?
2. Если логика приложения предполагает что-то кроме отправки HTML странички, например алгоритм (расчетный модуль), который что то будет считать (долго), лучше использовать сервер приложений? В этом случае веб сервер просто будет принимать http запросы?
3. Если обернуть в докер контейнер веб-сервер и сервер-приложений + БД, будет ли это считать микросервисом?

Comment: По моему мнению это очень мутные понятия. Микросервис это вообще архитектура построения приложений. Сервер это физический девайс, который доступен в сети, либо же программа, которая способна вести интеракцию с конечным пользователем. Сервер приложений вообще непонятно что конкретно это понятие описывает. Видимо последнее, о чем я сказал. Это все игра слов..

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, будьте любезны меня поправить.